# Loading a collection of Enums with Google app engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am using the Goole app engine datastore with Java and trying to load an Object with a List of Enums. Every time I load the object the List is null. The object is

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class ObjectToSave {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private List<AnEnum> anEnumList;

    //public getters and setters
}
```

The enum is simple

```
public enum AnEnum {
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2;
}
```

The code to save it is

```
ObjectToSave objectToSave = new ObjectToSave();
List<AnEnum> anEnumList = new ArrayList<AnEnum>();
anEnumList.add(AnEnum.VALUE_1);
objectToSave.setAnEnumList(anEnumList);
PersistenceManager pm = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();
try {
    pm.makePersistent(objectToSave);
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

The code to load it is

```
PersistenceManager pm = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();
try {
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(ObjectToSave.class.getSimpleName(), id);
    ObjectToSave objectToSave = pm.getObjectById(ObjectToSave.class, key);
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

I can view the data in the datastore using http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin and can see my List has been saved but it is not there when the object is loaded.

I created my project with the Eclipse plugin and haven't made any changes to the datastore settings as far as I know. So why id my Enum list null?

Comment: Can you show the code where you assign the list to anEnumList?

Comment: Are other fields in the object being saved properly?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the creation of the enum list. Also other values which I have not added here are being saved and the primary key is being set.

Comment: I've changed my question slightly as I can now see the data is saved but it is not loaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes but your List field is not in the default fetch group at loading so hence is not loaded. 
Read [JDO Fetch Groups](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jdo/fetchgroup.html). You could add it to the DFG, or enable a custom fetch group, or just "touch" the field before closing the PM.

--Andy ([DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org))

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating an instance of ObjectToSave?  The default value of all instance variable reference types is null, so unless you have (additional) code to create an instance of `List<AnEnum>` and assign it to `anEnumList`, null would be expected.

Comment: I am setting a value to the list with a debugger I can see its set before I save the object. I've updated the question to try and make this clearer.

Comment: Perhaps you need to mark your enum declaration as @PersistenceCapable?

Comment: "A Collection of child objects (of @PersistenceCapable classes) creates multiple entities with a one-to-many relationship. See Relationships."

From: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html#Collections

Comment: The child objects "AnEnum" aren't PersistenceCapable, neither should they be. Enums are supported persistable types by JDO